# Is it possible to use CSS to highlight adjacent, identical value table cells?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did several searches, but couldn't find anything quite similar to this. I did find the same question for **Excel**, but mine is for **HTML/CSS**: [Highlight cell if an adjacent cell in column has the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508211/highlight-cell-if-an-adjacent-cell-in-column-has-the-same-value) (Excel question).

---

Essentially I have a **sortable HTML table** with a bunch of values that can frequently be 100% identical. For example, often the **same GUID repeats in several rows**. Once I sort the table they end up adjacent to each other, and I want to highlight them both for clarity at that time (only when they are adjacent).

**Before I do this in Javascript, I was just wondering if there is a built-in feature in CSS to do this?** So many strange things seem to be possible in CSS these days.

Here is a **mock up** of what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: There is no selector in standard CSS that matches text content. Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text), or [CSS selector based on element text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text), or [CSS rule based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777357/css-rule-based-on-content)

Comment: I realize that your question is slightly more specific than the duplicates I've marked, but in order for this to work, CSS would have to be able to do the following: 1) Retrieve text from an element. 2) Store the text to compare to other values. 3) Be able to compare non-sibling elements (I assume your content is in `<td>` tags, children of separate `<tr>` tags.) - CSS cannot do any of this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with pure CSS. You must use JavaScript.